# Extracting data from a pyspark dataframe using conditions from other dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, hadoop, join, pyspark

I have a pysprak dataframe and a need to extract selected rows from it based of the condition of
other 2 single columned dataframes. I tried using join but its too slow as the data is huge.
I thought of using partitioning or lookup() in spark but i couldn't implement those as i am new to pyspark.
Please suggest me how to do this efficiently.
Here are the example dataframes:

```
main dataframe:

  df1 = DataFrame({'CID': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],'Name': ['B7', 'B4', 'B0', 'B3'],'Group':[23,34,45,67]})

conditional dataframes:

  df2 = DataFrame({'CID': ['A4', 'A3', 'A7', 'A8']})

  df3=Dataframe({'Group':[33,42,66,90]})
```

I tried doing join but it's inefficient.

```
df1=df1.join(df2,df1.CID==df2.CID)


df1=df1.join(df3,df1.Group==df3.Group)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is, joining the dataframes. Here's few tips to make the joins efficient -

1. Broadcast df2 and df3 if their size is small.
2. Sort the Dataframes based on join key and repartition before joining.